# Undefined variable: myquery - query was empty

Tags: php, sql, rating

i keep getting the error "Undefined variable: myquery - query was empty" i've tried many different things for hours and still can't get it to work. I am very new to php and finding it confusing. So please explain in good detail or link me to something useful so that i can understand it more.
here is the code:

```
 <?php
include_once("scripts/connect_db.php");
$totals = "";
$rating = "";
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT `ratings` FROM `blog_posts` WHERE `id`='1'");
$result = mysql_query($myquery) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
$myNums = $row["ratings"];
    $kaboom = explode(",", $myNums);
    $result = array_count_values($kaboom);
    foreach($result as $key => $value){
        if ($value =="1"){
            $howMany = "person";
            }else{
                $howMany = "people";
            }
            if($key ==""){
                $pic = "images/starsNorm.png";
            }
            else if($key == "1"){
                $stars = "star";
                $pic = "images/1lit.png";
            }else if($key == "2"){
                $stars = "stars";
                $pic = "images/2lit.png";
            }else if($key == "3"){
                $stars = "stars";
                $pic = "images/3lit.png";
            }else if($key == "4"){
                $stars = "stars";
                $pic = "images/4lit.png";
            }else if($key == "5"){
                $stars = "stars";
                $pic = "images/5lit.png";
            }
$totals .= '<p class="small" style="color:#32CD32;">' . $key . ' ' . $stars . ': <img src="' . $pic . '" alt="stars" />
        ' . $value . ' ' .$howMany . '</p>';
    }
    $count = count($kaboom);
    $sum = array_sum($kaboom);
    $avg = $sum / $count;
    $roundit = floor($avg);

    if($roundit == 0) {
        $rating = '<p class="small" style="color:#32CD32;">This ... has not yet been rated. You can be first!</p>';
    }else if ($count == 1) {
        $rating = '<p class="small" style="color:#32CD32;">Current Article Rating: ' . $roundit . '/5 stars <img id="myStars" src="images/starsNorm.png"
        alt="stars"/></p>';
    }else if($count > 1) {
        $rating = '<p class="small" style="color:#32CD32;">Current Article Rating: ' . $roundit . '/5 stars <img id="myStars" src="images/starsNorm.png"
        alt="stars"/></p>';
    }else{
        $rating = "sorry there is an error in the system... please try refreshing the page";
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This line is invalid:

```
$result = mysql_query($myquery) or die(mysql_error());
```

You aren't defining $myquery anywhere which is exactly what the error message is telling you.

I'm guessing the line above it should just be a string and then that's the variable you want to pass in.

E.g.

```
$sql = "SELECT `ratings` FROM `blog_posts` WHERE `id`='1'";
$result = mysql_query( $sql ) or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont have defined $myquery variable. You have $sql. Try this:

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `ratings` FROM `blog_posts` WHERE `id`='1'");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {  

}
```

Comment: i've tried that but now im getting the error: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, array given

Comment: connect, query, fetch code is correct then it could be that mysql_connect is connecting but not seeing your database. Run this code to ensure that your database is being found

Answer (score 0):

if you're sure that the connect, query, fetch code is correct then it could be that mysql_connect is connecting but not seeing your database. Run this code to ensure that your database is being found

```
mysql_connect('localhost') or die ("Connect error");

$res = mysql_query("SHOW DATABASES");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($res)) {
    echo $row[0], '<br/>';
}
```

if it's not being found then you need to amend the privileges on your database. For example go into the Privileges tab on the Database in question, make the User name Any User and check the privileges that apply.

Comment: when i run that code it says information_schema
test is this correct or should it say the name of the database i am using